# Ajax get function with endpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I have an endpoint on the server:

```
app.get('/A/:A_Id/B/:B_Id/C?', callbackFunction);
```

After I type "`http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/A/1/B/1/C?startTimeUtc=03:00:00&endTimeUtc=05:00:00`" the server responds with data in callbackFunction, I can see the data in address `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/A/1/B/1/C?startTimeUtc=03:00:00&endTimeUtc=05:00:00` (the startTimeUtc and endTimeUtc can change depending on the user inputs),
but I am not able to get data with an ajax get function:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/A/:A_ID/B/:B_ID/C?', success: function(result){
      // result is NaN
}
```

What should be the correct endpoint in this case?

Comment: It looks like the server is expecting the querystring parameters in the url.  Did you try it with the full working url?

Comment: i mean... `:A_id` isn't `1`.

Comment: I mean the startTime and endTime can change depending on the user inputs,  do I have to provide the full url  each time for the ajax call to retrieve the data?

Comment: you do have to provide a url that contains the data that you expect said ajax request to send. jQuery isn't going to replace `:A_id` with a value for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're not actually providing any data to the ajax call.

```
API_URL = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/A/" + A_ID + "/B/" + B_ID + "/C"
$.ajax({
    type:'GET', //mostly here for readability; is default for ajax
    url:API_URL,
    data:{
        startTimeUtc:user_input_for_start_time
        endTimeUtc:user_input_for_end_time
    }
}).done(function(result){
    console.log(result);
}).always(function(result, status){
    console.log(result);
    console.log(status);
});
```

Not sure whether the always will help you at all, but thought it might be worth a shot. You also need to include the full URL. As a wikipedia api example, it'd be : `"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"`. i.e. you just need to go to the ?, and then the ? is optional for GET calls (regardless of whether or not the type is supplied, see [jQuery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)).

An alternative approach is pasting the entire URL:
`url:API_URL + "?startTimeUtc=03:00:00&endTimeUtc=05:00:00"`. I personally prefer using data, but it's totally up to you.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but startTimeUtc and endTimeUtc can change depending on the user inputs

Comment: Question mark should be stripped from endpoint API_URL because HTTP method is explicit GET here

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/A/" + A_ID + "/B/" + B_ID + "/C?startTimeUtc=" + startTime + "&endTimeUtc=" + endTime;

$.get( url, function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Where `A_ID`, `B_ID`, `startTime` and `endTime` are the variables containing the respective values.